# Vue 3: The console says the state has the ID, but in the vuex store, it's "null"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, state-management

Im using Vue 3 and in a component I create an item in the database. When I console log the response it has the ID. In the the "UPDATE_STATE" the payload and the state also has the ID we can see it in the console. But after that the vuex store DOESN'T have the ID. How is this happening?

**The create function**

```
createItem(context: any) {
  console.log(moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

  const data = {
    ...state,
    creationDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    dueDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  };
  console.log(data);
  axios
    .post("/link-is-here/", data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${context.rootState.user.accessToken}`,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("res: " + JSON.stringify(res))
      context.commit("UPDATE_STATE", res.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},
```

**The UPDATE_STATE function**

```
[UPDATE_STATE](state: any, payload: any) {

  console.log("payload:" + JSON.stringify(payload))
  state = payload
  console.log("state:" + JSON.stringify(state))
},
```

[image: The ID's are the in the console log]

[image: The ID is null in the state]

Answer (score 0):

In your example you rewrite state variable, so vuex don't get any notifications that something in state was altered

try to inject data field by field

```
import Vue from 'vue';



[UPDATE_STATE](state: any, payload: any) {
  console.log("payload:", payload)

  for(const field in payload){
    Vue.set(state, field, payload.state) 
    // that's almost same as state.field = payload.state but make new data reactive (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)
  }
 
  console.log("state:", state)
},
```

or just

```
Vue.set(state, 'scopeName', payload)
```

Comment: Google says that Vue.set was removed in Vue 3. Sorry I forgot to mention that Im using Vue 3

Comment: so use state[field] = payload[field] instead